# Does anyone have any experience with a mouthpiece for golf?

Tags: equipment, golf

I recently read the following article: [A MOUTHPIECE FOR GOLF](http://www.golfdigest.com/magazine/2011-11/kaspriske-fitness-column#ixzz2lm3CgLq0).

Sounds silly, but clenching your teeth can hurt your game.

**Is there any evidence to suggest that such a product may be helpful?

I guess the real question does wearing a mouthpiece allow you to clinch your jaw but not have the side affects of the over all body tension?**

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. For the most part, I see an advertisement for a golf mouthpiece as featured in Golf Digest. I removed the obvious copy-paste and placed emphasis on the question (I believe) you are asking.

Comment: This isn't a real question. (_Does anyone have any experience with this?_). Some may say _yes_, some may say _no_ - your "question" is then answered but so what? A better question may be to ask, for example, "Is there any evidence to suggest that such a product may be helpful".

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience using a mouthpiece in golf. I do not recognize myself clenching my jaw in golf, but the closest I would come to such an occurrence is on the downswing of a "power" type of shot.

Aside: Perhaps clenching the jaw in golf is akin to [grunting in tennis](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/grunting-in-tennis).

However, the article states something I do agree with:

> the best swings are typically generated from a relaxed state

To illustrate an example, I was facing a tree on my second shot on a par-5 from the rough. I chose 7-iron as 6-iron was risking hitting my ball against the top of the tree. I hit the shot 200+ yards (I typically hit a 7-iron around 185 yards) over the tree to 20 feet from the hole. My swing thought was to hit the shot solid, and I did.

I illustrated the example above to provide that, based on my experience, a "relaxed" swing is the byproduct of practice, having a concise [swing thought](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/3131/527), and execution moreso than the clenching, or restriction thereof, of my jaw.

Comment: I agree with you about the swing thought I always have better rounds when I am relaxed as well. I am more curious about the release of cortisol into your system when you clinch your jaw causing tension in the rest of your body. I guess the real question does wearing a mouthpiece allow you to clinch your jaw but not have the side affects of the over all body tension?

Comment: I will have to play a round clenching my jaw with and without a mouthpiece to see if tension is present or not and if it affects my round. I'm not versed in the scientific details, but if I'm clenching my jaw, whether or not there's reinforcement of a mouthpiece, I'm clenching my jaw.